# XMPP reply from GAE to Google+ doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, google-plus

I've noticed errors in my Google App Engine Log while parsing messages. The stack trace was unhelpful to diagnose the problem, so I wrote a small message dumper inspired by Google's implementation of [InboundMessageParser](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/xmpp/InboundMessageParser.java&type=cs).

```
public class ChatRequestParser extends HttpRequestParser {

    public static Map<String, String> parseMessage(HttpServletRequest request)
    throws IOException {
        try {
            Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MimeMultipart multipart = parseMultipartRequest(request);
            int parts = multipart.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
                BodyPart part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                String fieldName = getFieldName(part);
                String fieldValue = getTextContent(part);
                message.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
            }
            return message;
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Could not parse incoming request.", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I found out that Google+ sends two messages for each message, only one of which contains a body (Gmail Talk client sends only one message).

Here is the first message, without a body:

```
{to=xxx@appspot.com, stanza=<message to="xxx@appspot.com" type="chat"
from="yyy@gmail.com/TalkGadgetD9F45A83" xmlns="jabber:client">
<cha:composing xmlns:cha="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
<nos:x value="disabled" xmlns:nos="google:nosave"/>
<arc:record otr="false" xmlns:arc="http://jabber.org/protocol/archive"/>
</message>, from=yyy@gmail.com/TalkGadgetD9F45A83}
```

And the second one is (my payload is many asterisks, mails changed):

```
{to=xxx@appspot.com, body=**********************************, 
stanza=<message to="xxx@appspot.com" type="chat" 
id="7279D79D0.17809585028724073_:sl" from="yyy@gmail.com/TalkGadgetD9F45A83"
xmlns="jabber:client"><body>**********************************</body>
<cha:active xmlns:cha="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
<nos:x value="disabled" xmlns:nos="google:nosave"/><arc:record otr="false"
xmlns:arc="http://jabber.org/protocol/archive"/></message>,
from=yyy@gmail.com/TalkGadgetD9F45A83}
```

Since the first message doesn't have a body calling parseMessage() on XMPPService throws exception. Has anyone noticed this problem?

Now I am catching the IllegalArgumentException and throwing away meaningless messages, but the real problem is, that **the reply to the valid message doesn't arrive back to Google+** client, while works perfectly with Gmail and also with my Jabber client on Linux.

I've filed [issue 6467](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6467).

Comment: Investigating this now -- thanks for reporting and also adding the external issue. I've marked it as 'Started'. Will update here and on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the crash when no body is set and parseMessage is called, and I'm fixing it. Thanks for finding it!

However, I can't repro the "send reply doesn't work" bug. I have code like this:

```
  XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();
  Message message = xmpp.parseMessage(req);
  Message reply = new MessageBuilder().withFromJid(message.getRecipientJids()[0])
    .withRecipientJids(message.getFromJid())
    .withBody("Back at you!")
    .build();
  xmpp.sendMessage(reply);
```

And I receive the reply both in Google+ and in Gmail. What are you doing differently?

Comment: I had `.withMessageType(MessageType.NORMAL)`, if I remove it, the message is received by Google+ -- (the default should be `CHAT`).

Comment: One note: it works even without setting the FromJid.  Is it bad if I leave the withFromJid() out? Is it guaranteed that my app would be the first recipientJid? Otherwise, how can I figure out the correct fromJid?

Comment: In the parsed message, it is guaranteed that your app will be the first recipient JID. Leaving it out is okay but won't behave correctly if the user is subscribed to "foo@yourappid.appspotchat.com" but you reply from "yourappid@appspot.com" (the default from JID).

Investigating the MessageType.NORMAL bug now -- thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Good to know, now I feel better about `message.getRecipientJids()[0]`, thank you.